# Backend deletion inside the array

Tags: java, node.js, django, backend

I am wondering what is the best way to `PATCH` an array of things/ objects.

Let's assume I have `records` array inside my model and I want to add some records to it using my frontend application. I'm sending just those in the request as:

`records: [{ name: 'record_1' }, { name: 'record_2' }]`

What if I now want to delete `record_2`? Should my approach be:

1. Send `records: [{ name: 'record_1' }]` as a whole, so the backend knows that we deleted the `record_2`
2. Send the array with some flag like `deleted: true` so it looks like this:
   `records: [{ name: 'record_1' }, { name: 'record_2', deleted: true }]`

Frontend wise it is easier to do the first one, but how about the backend?

Comment: The first option leads to a potential other problem: Should you ever just want to update one object of your collection you are now forced to always send the whole package instead of just that one object. I would prefer a version where you send a specific "deletion" message for a specified object.

Comment: what will be the maximum size of the records array?, how many element do you plan to add there

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle Probably up to 50

Answer (score 0):

Following REST principles, you should use DELETE request specifying the identifier of the entity you're going to delete. 
In your case, you can send something like this:

```
curl -X "DELETE" http://your.backend.address/endpoint/record_2
```

or with JS:

```
fetch(url + '/' + "record_2", {
method: 'delete'
})
```

After you received positive response (200 OK), you can delete it on fronted.

Comment: Not really helpful if you want to delete multiple records. In this case you would have to perform multiple requests.

Comment: then you can use request body to pass these identifiers as list